# Does a Boros Skyknight have to mount their Skyjek Roc, or can it act independently?

Tags: dnd-5e, mount, mounted-combat, factions, ravnica

In *Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*, after a Boros Legionnaire is level 5 and has renown of at least 5, the player can become a [skyknight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/ggtr/boros-legion#SkyknightSpecialRole) (p. 43). The text states:

> Skyknights mounted on Skyjek rocs patrol the skies above Ravnica — a
>   regular reminder of the Boros and their concern for justice. If you
>   meet the prerequisites, you can become a skyknight, assuming no
>   official objects. You are assigned a [Skyjek roc](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/skyjek-roc) (see chapter 6 for the
>   stat block) to use as a mount when carrying out your guild
>   responsibilities. Using the roc for personal matters is a significant
>   violation of regulations

Does this mean that a player needs to use the Roc as a mount? Or could they use it as an independent creature, so that it can attack and such on its own turn?

I started at a high level as a paladin so I already have a griffon as a mount, so is the Roc mostly just redundant, or can it attack?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour], and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 6):

The Roc is used as a mount, not as a "companion" (such as a BeastMaster's companion). As such it needs to be abide by the mount rulings if you're strictly following the written rules. This means if you are not riding it you are also not controlling it.

All creatures including mounts can attack on their own. However they cannot be controlled in the same way a BeastMaster can. They will act on their own independent of what you want them to do. While riding them you can decide if it acts on its own or with you. Having an extra mount is not akin to having another member of the party to fight along your side as the rules are written.

Is it possible to train the Roc or the Griffin to obey your commands? Perhaps. However this is something you and your DM should decide further. Having a Griffon and a Roc joining you in battle and being controlled by you may lead to an unbalanced character.

If you really want to use both I would recommend discussing with your DM the rules for mounts, rules for familiars, and rules for animal companions to decide which one is most acceptable.